# How to deploy Syncthing (Open source alternative yo bittorrent-sync) to OPENSHIFT Online?

Tags: synchronization, openshift, bittorrent, syncthing

I was trying to set up [Syncthing](http://syncthing.net/), on OPENSHIFT Online as DIY project. I extracted the binary & pushed it to Openshift. As I can not use `0.0.0.0` on Openshift I used `$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP` for listing on 8080.

But when I run (after ssh to server) `./syncthing -home="$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/syncthing/.config"`, It started the web GUI, but I could not access it from dns.

I filed a issue at githhub: https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/issues/1310

But I think, it has something to do with the restriction that Openshift has on PORTS & IPS.

**So How do I run Syncthing on Openshift?**

This is my OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/diy/syncthing/.config/config.xml (manually created):

`<configuration version="7">
    <folder id="default" path="/var/lib/openshift/54da534a58773ca00a6/app-root/runtime/repo/diy/syncthing/sync" ro="false" rescanIntervalS="60" ignorePerms="false">
        <device id="GTD5SPM-ZNKRARD-Y6JFM3C-PZIC56R-XWOAPIN-CR2ZDTG-EKJMN2H-GJMPKQ6"></device>
        <versioning></versioning>
        <lenientMtimes>false</lenientMtimes>
        <copiers>0</copiers>
        <pullers>0</pullers>
        <hashers>0</hashers>
    </folder>
    <device id="YBS7UI3-5Y7V7W2-KPTZZR4-LU3Y5TH-UTE6JJS-ID55PT3-GSI73NW-ZBOHSQU" name="ex-std-node515.prod.rhcloud.com" compression="false" introducer="false">
        <address>dynamic</address>
    </device>
    <gui enabled="true" tls="true">
        <address>127.12.74.128:8080</address>
        <user>jb</user>
        <password>$2a$10$EKXXXXX...</password>
        <apikey>O80CDOJ9LVXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</apikey>
    </gui>
    <options>
    <listenAddress>127.12.74.128:24097</listenAddress>
        <globalAnnounceServer>udp4://announce.syncthing.net:22026</globalAnnounceServer>
        <globalAnnounceEnabled>true</globalAnnounceEnabled>
        <localAnnounceEnabled>true</localAnnounceEnabled>
        <localAnnouncePort>21025</localAnnouncePort>
        <localAnnounceMCAddr>[ff32::5222]:21026</localAnnounceMCAddr>
        <maxSendKbps>0</maxSendKbps>
        <maxRecvKbps>0</maxRecvKbps>
        <reconnectionIntervalS>60</reconnectionIntervalS>
        <startBrowser>false</startBrowser>
        <upnpEnabled>true</upnpEnabled>
        <upnpLeaseMinutes>0</upnpLeaseMinutes>
        <upnpRenewalMinutes>30</upnpRenewalMinutes>
        <urAccepted>0</urAccepted>
        <urUniqueID></urUniqueID>
        <restartOnWakeup>true</restartOnWakeup>
        <autoUpgradeIntervalH>12</autoUpgradeIntervalH>
        <keepTemporariesH>24</keepTemporariesH>
        <cacheIgnoredFiles>true</cacheIgnoredFiles>
        <progressUpdateIntervalS>5</progressUpdateIntervalS>
        <symlinksEnabled>true</symlinksEnabled>
    </options>
</configuration>`

Comment: What do the logs from the application say?